# nlog interop not logging

Tags: c#, .net, interop, nlog

I am using c# and .net v4.6.1 in a dll library which is being exposed as a com interop assembly. It work fine when running it from a .net client, but when i call it from the actual Com component, there is no logging.  Is there anything special i need to do for interop dll's?  I am using an Nlog.dll.nlog file for configuration and it contains the following...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
      autoReload="true"
      throwExceptions="true"
      internalLogLevel="Trace" internalLogFile="c:\ProgramData\Clearview\Logs\Server\NlogInternal.log">

    <targets>
        <target name="logFile" xsi:type="File" fileName="c:/ProgramData/Clearview/Logs/Server/Mapping.log"
            layout="${longdate} | ${level:uppercase=false} | ${message}" />

        <target name="coloredConsole" xsi:type="ColoredConsole" layout="${longdate} | ${level:uppercase=false} | ${message}" />

        <target name="eventLog" xsi:type="EventLog" log="ClearviewMappingServices" layout="${longdate} | ${level:uppercase=false} | ${message}" />
    </targets>

    <rules>

        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="logFile" />
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="coloredConsole" />
        <logger name="*" minlevel="Error" writeTo="eventLog" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have it set to embed interop types?

Comment: Which referemce are you asking this about?  The assembly i am creating is a Com Interop assembly and it has a reference to NLog in it.  NLog's "Embed Interop Types" is set to false.